# AngularFirev16 "Auth instance has already been used to make a network call" upon hotreload using emulator

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, firebase-tools

I successfully upgraded AngularFire to version 16 and now I want to use the emulator with modular mode. I tried setting it up like in the example provided in the official samples found here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/samples/modular/src/app/app.module.ts

This is a snippet of my app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // .. //
  ],
  imports: [
  provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      if (environment.useEmulators) {
        connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://localhost:9099', {disableWarnings: true});
      }
      return auth;
    }),
    provideFirestore(() => {
      const firestore = getFirestore();
      if (environment.useEmulators) {
        connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, 'localhost', 8080);
      }
      enableMultiTabIndexedDbPersistence(firestore).then(
        () => resolvePersistenceEnabled(true),
        () => resolvePersistenceEnabled(false)
      );
      return firestore;
    }),
    provideFunctions(() => {
      const functions = getFunctions();
      if (environment.useEmulators) {
        connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, 'localhost', 5001);
      }
      return functions;
    }),
    // .. //
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: environment.firebaseConfig
    },

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

With this I am able to login to my application using credentials from the auth emulator. But as soon as the app is being hotreloaded, i get following error in the console:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: Auth instance has already been used to make a network call. Auth can no longer be configured to use the emulator. Try calling "connectAuthEmulator()" sooner. (auth/emulator-config-failed).
```

I would appreciate any help with this issue.

What I found so far is that upon login, the first call to the identity toolkit is correctly directed towards localhost.

```
http://localhost:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key={{myKey}}
```

but when reloaded it is directed towards production

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key={{myKey}}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that you have the `onAuthStateChanged()` listener running and do not have it configured to "shut down" when that code gets unloaded/reloaded.

Comment: thanks, Greg for your answer. I am using a simple implementation of github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web (email auth provider) therefore I am not handling onAuthStateChange myself. It looks like firebaseui is not yet supporting v9 nor v10 of firebase according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui

Comment: See the third code snippet in [the section of the docs here](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web?tab=readme-ov-file#starting-the-sign-in-flow).

Comment: BTW: `Firebase UI` is not a heavily maintained project.  According to the docs, they still don't support Firebase Client SDK v9 or v10 directly.  Instead you are expected to use the `compat` version of the SDK which is not the recommended SDK to use in general.